# Uploading images to Firebase with Spring boot

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Hello everyone I'm currently working on the submission of images on firebase storage from my spring boot api, currently everything works I can submit my images but the public url of the image is not available, I would like to know how to get a public url of my image from my api

```
public void uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, String path) throws IOException {
    String objectName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
    StorageOptions storageOptions = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
            .setProjectId("my-project")
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials
                    .fromStream(new ClassPathResource("firebase_admin.json").getInputStream()))
            .build();
    Storage storage = storageOptions.getService();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket-name", objectName);

    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(multipartFile.getContentType()).build();

    Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, multipartFile.getBytes());

    System.out.println("UPLOAD FILE" + multipartFile.getName() + " " + multipartFile.getSize() + " octet");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is public, here the URL pattern

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket-name>/<objectName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the alt parameter in the url to get the download URL like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<bucket-name>/o/<objet-name>?alt=media
```

Get more detail in this post : https://medium.com/teamarimac/file-upload-and-download-with-spring-boot-firebase-af068bc62614